# What is the semicolon reserved for in URLs?

Tags: url, uri, character, rfc3986

The [RFC 3986 URI: Generic Syntax](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) specification lists a semicolon as a reserved (sub-delim) character:

```
reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims

gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"

sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

What is the reserved purpose of the ";" of the semicolon in URIs? For that matter, what is the purpose of the other sub-delims (I'm only aware of purposes for "&", "+", and "=")?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is an explanation at the end of section 3.3.

> Aside from dot-segments in
> hierarchical paths, a path segment is
> considered opaque by the generic
> syntax. URI producing applications
> often use the reserved characters
> allowed in a segment to delimit
> scheme-specific or
> dereference-handler-specific
> subcomponents.  For example, the
> semicolon (";") and equals ("=")
> reserved characters are often used
> to delimit parameters and parameter
> values applicable to that segment.
> The comma (",") reserved character is
> often used forsimilar purposes.
> For example, one URI producer might
> use a segment uch as "name;v=1.1"
> to indicate a reference to version 1.1
> of "name", whereas another might
> use a segment such as "name,1.1" to
> indicate the same. Parameter types
> may be defined by scheme-specific
> semantics, but in most cases the
> syntax of a parameter is specific to
> the implementation of the URI's
> dereferencing algorithm.

In other words, it is reserved so that people who want a delimited list of something in the URL can safely use `;` as a delimiter even if the parts contain `;`, as long as the contents are percent-encoded. In other words, you can do this:

```
foo;bar;baz%3bqux
```

and interpret it as three parts: `foo`, `bar`, `baz;qux`. If semicolon were not a reserved character, the `;` and `%3b`would be equivalent, so the URI would be incorrectly interpreted as four parts: `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, `qux`.

Comment: In short, reserved, but for nothing in particular.  We use it to encode some information in RESTful queries.

Comment: Can somebody share an example of this used in real word web services?

Comment: Some special meaning for the `;` in HTTP URLs?

Answer (score 10):

The intent is clearer if you go back to [older versions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396) of the specification:

```
  path_segments = segment *( "/" segment )
  segment       = *pchar *( ";" param )
```

> Each path segment may include a
> sequence of parameters, indicated by the semicolon ";" character.

I believe it has its origins in [FTP URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.2.2)s.

Answer (score 5):

[Section 3.3 covers this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) - it's an opaque delimiter a URI-producing application can use if convenient:

> Aside from dot-segments in
> hierarchical paths, a path segment is
> considered opaque by the generic
> syntax. URI producing applications
> often use the reserved characters
> allowed in a segment to delimit
> scheme-specific or
> dereference-handler-specific
> subcomponents. For example, the
> semicolon (";") and equals ("=")
> reserved characters are often used to
> delimit parameters and parameter
> values applicable to that segment. The
> comma (",") reserved character is
> often used for similar purposes. For
> example, one URI producer might use a
> segment such as "name;v=1.1" to
> indicate a reference to version 1.1 of
> "name", whereas another might use a
> segment such as "name,1.1" to indicate
> the same. Parameter types may be
> defined by scheme-specific semantics,
> but in most cases the syntax of a
> parameter is specific to the
> implementation of the URI's
> dereferencing algorithm.

Comment: What is an *"opaque delimiter"*? In what way is it opaque?

Answer (score 4):

There are some conventions around its current usage that are interesting.  These speak to when to use a semicolon or comma.  From the book "RESTful Web Services":

> Use punctuation characters to separate multiple pieces of data at the same level of hierarchy.  Use commas when the order of the items matters, ...  Use semicolons when the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

Since 2014, path segments are known to contribute to [Reflected File Download attacks](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-14/materials/eu-14-Hafif-Reflected-File-Download-A-New-Web-Attack-Vector.pdf). Let's assume we have a vulnerable API that reflects whatever we send to it:

```
https://google.com/s?q=rfd%22||calc||

{"results":["q", "rfd\"||calc||","I love rfd"]}
```

Now, this is harmless in a browser as it's JSON, so it's not going to be rendered, but the browser will rather offer to download the response as a file. Now here's the path segments come to help (for the attacker):

```
https://google.com/s;/setup.bat;?q=rfd%22||calc||
```

Everything between semicolons (`;/setup.bat;`) will be **not** sent to the web service, but instead the browser will interpret it as the file name... to save the API response.

Now, a file called `setup.bat` will be downloaded and run without asking about dangers of running files downloaded from the Internet (because it contains the word `"setup"` in its name). The contents will be interpreted as a Windows batch file, and the `calc.exe` command will be run.

Prevention:

- sanitize your API's input (in this case, they should just allow alphanumerics); escaping is not sufficient
- add `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="whatever.txt"` on APIs that are not going to be rendered; Google was missing the `filename` part which actually made the attack easier
- add `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header to API responses

Answer (score 0):

I found the following use cases:

It's the final character of an HTML entity:

*[List of XML and HTML character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)*

> To use one of these character entity references in an HTML or XML
> document, enter an ampersand followed by the entity name and a
> semicolon, e.g., & for the ampersand ("&").

Apache Tomcat 7 (or newer versions?!) us it as `path parameter`:

*[Three Semicolon Vulnerabilities](https://superevr.com/blog/2011/three-semicolon-vulnerabilities)*

> Apache Tomcat is one example of a web server that supports "Path
> Parameters". A path parameter is extra content after a file name,
> separated by a semicolon. Any arbitrary content after a semicolon does
> not affect the landing page of a web browser. This means that
> http://example.com/index.jsp;derp will still return index.jsp, and not
> some error page.

URI scheme splits by it the MIME and data:

*[Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)*

> It can contain an optional character set parameter, separated from the
> preceding part by a semicolon (;) .
>
> ```
> <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
> AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
> 9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
> ```

And there was a bug in IIS 5 and IIS 6 to bypass file upload restrictions:

*[Unrestricted File Upload](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload)*

> Blacklisting File Extensions This protection might be bypassed by: ...
> by adding a semi-colon character after the forbidden extension and
> before the permitted one (e.g. "file.asp;.jpg")

**Conclusion:**

Do not use semicolons in URLs or they could accidentally produce an HTML entity or URI scheme.