# What are the intended usages of each URI "reserved character"?

Tags: url, character-encoding, uri, url-encoding

We always see reserved characters like `/`, `#`, `&` in URLs; but what are the intended usages of less common ones like `@`, `[`, `]`, `,`?

I haven't been able to find a good explanation of what these characters are reserved *for*.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters) and [section 2.2 here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `@` and `:`: for HTTP login data for a host (`http://john:password@example.com`)

  - `:` also separates the host from the port (`http://example.com:1337`)
  - note that `@` is obviously used in the path of `mailto` URIs, but [allowed in the HTTP URI path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737890/1591669), too
- `[` and `]`: for [CURIEs](http://www.w3.org/TR/curie/) (`[db:resource/Albert_Einstein]`)
- `,`: could be used to delimit (query) parameters
- `;`: see this question: [What is the semicolon reserved for in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2163803/1591669)

Answer (score 0):

@ is for adding username and password to the url, so you could do `http://username:password@host.com`

Comment: Speculation on the rest: precautionary removal of characters they expected this and other protocols to use later, even without a particular use in mind.  The RFC says `+`, `,`, and `$` are reserved for query strings, but no  use is specified.  I've seen brosers that handle these characters without incident.