# What is the params part of the tuple returned from Python urlparse?

Tags: python, urlparse

I am doing some validation on URLs and I can not find a good example to express the `params` part of the returned tuple from `urlparse()`.

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html :

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse('http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html')
>>> o   
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.cwi.nl:80', path='/%7Eguido/Python.html',
        params='', query='', fragment='')
```

I have done my best, SO and Goog searches are not finding success.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163803/what-is-the-semicolon-reserved-for-in-urls) for an explanation. The `params` refer to a very rarely used feature to include semicolon separated parameters in URIs.

Comment: answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988614/what-are-the-url-parameters-element-at-position-3-in-urlparse-result)

Comment: OMG thanks so much, I figured as much. Maybe my phrasing will help others find the answer.