# I don't understand this URI and more

Tags: url, uri, urn

I have this URI http://a/b/c/d;p?q and I don't understand the ";". What does it do? I was told that "p" is a parameter, but who does receive it?

Also, I want to know the different between absolute URI, base URI, relative URI and URI reference.

Thank you in advance. ( ^_^)b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run from the structure of URL. You can read more about it in http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/what-every-developer-should-know-about-urls/ and http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding (good examples)

> `<scheme>://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<path>;<parameters>?<query>#<fragment>`
>
> Each path segment may include a sequence of parameters, indicated by the semicolon ";" character.

**Parameters** (delimited with semicolon) should be processed by web server. However it doesn't have wide usage and **might not** be supported by web server.
Its usage is discussed in these SO posts: 
[Semicolon as URL query separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3481664/4573999), https://stackoverflow.com/a/26489224/4573999

**Absolute URL** is a URL that at least contains **base**: protocol (ex., `http://`, `ftp://`) and site name (first segment of URL). Ex., http://google.com/search. Here we have *base* `http://google.com` and path (segment) `/search`

**Base URL** defines the point to start off for all relative URLs in document. Ex., `<base href="http://example.com/myfolder">`

> The HTML Base Element () specifies the base URL to use for all
>   relative URLs contained within a document. There can be only one
>    element in a document.

See [MDN description for this tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

**Relative URL** specifies path to a resource starting from a *base*. Ex., `href="/images/funny.png"`.

If *relative URL* start with `/` it goes from the root of the base (site name), i.e. ignores the path supplied in *base*.

By default if base is not supplied it is assumed to be the URL of the document that contains the *relative URL*. It is convenient to supply link to resources (like images) using relative URLs. In this case you can easily move domain where document is published and links won't get broken.

**URL reference** AFAIK is a synonym to any URL. It stresses the fact the URL is a reference not an object itself.